# How to set tooltip color in Cocoa

Tags: xcode, cocoa, user-interface

Tool tips that I have set for some textboxes show up with a grey background. I thought yellow was the default. Where/how is the bg color (and text color set)? I can't find it in the XCode docs, none of my 5 books, or the Apple Dev stuff.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: The tooltips were set in IB. There is no code.